# Can I fly with Qatar Airways on a one-way ticket?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas

So I am flying with qatar airways getting a one way ticket from the UK to india. The journey is from manchester to doha then doha to india. (Doha being a connecting flight and I would only stay there for an hour or 2. Going through security then my gate and waiting for my flight). And india being my destination.

I checked India's entry requirements and it stated passport and sufficient visa which I do have. I have an oci card(indian life long visa) which allows me to come and go as I please.

I checked Qatar's visa requirements and it said a visa is not needed if on transit if you have an onward ticket. Is this onward ticket a ticket from doha to india? Or is it a return flight? I will be staying with my family in india and i'm not sure if or when I want to come back so a return ticket wouldn't make sense in my situation.

Please someone advise me. If getting a return ticket is better and will avoid any hassle then please let me know.

Also does qatar airways not allow you to board the flight if you have a one way ticket and not return? As many people have said that many airlines don't allow you to board if you have a one way ticket.

http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/visa-and-passport-requirements.page#

Comment: I think you wrote UAE by mistake, since you are traveling through Qatar.

Comment: @burhan Khalid oops sorry bro

Comment: One query though, is this the first time you are going to India, considering you have an OCI card ?

Comment: @Dumbcorder no... but it is the first time I'm going alone...we used to get return tickets and never flew with an OCI card..I know I probably sound stupid but I just wanted to be safe than sorry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An onward ticket means a ticket out of Doha, which you obviously have.

Airlines don't care about whether you have a return ticket or not.  What they care about is whether you have the valid paperwork to enter your destination country - otherwise they can be fined and be held responsible for returning you to where you came from.

In your case, that would mean that they will check that you meet the requirements to enter India. If entering India required a return ticket (which for some people it does) then the airline would enforce that - but as you've said you do not need a return flight to enter India, then Qatar will not enforce that you need one.

Comment: Thank you for your response I'm sorry if i sounded stupid but you have cleared a lot up for me so thanks. I have read online that some airlines do not allow to board the aircraft if you don't show a return ticket could this be the case with qatar airways? And for india I have an oci card which is a life long visa and I can come and go whenever I want

Comment: @IramAhmed The concern about return ticket is that on a *tourist* visa, or similar, you often need a return ticket to show you intend to leave again.  You're not in that situation, so you should be okay.